# C# XAML wpf textbox clipped at the bottom & does not show entire text

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

Im new to XAML, and I inherited a tool that needed a hex file viewer added.

Anyways I have my logic working however , the "TextBox" that shows the hex representation of my file is clipped/cut-off at the bottom.

How can I resolve this issue, so I can see bottom of the text box & also see bottom arrow of the scrollbar?

**This is my XAML ( I surrounded the relevant part of the xaml TabItem tag with START & END comments):**

```
   [![<Window x:Class="XYZ.ZipIR.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ZipIR Compression Tool" Height="454" Width="1186" Name="MainWindow">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1178" Name="MainGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="91*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="196*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="891*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TabControl Margin="0,20,3,10" Name="tabControl1" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Width="auto">
                <TabItem Header="Import" Name="tabItem1" Margin="-2,-2,2,-1">

            <Grid Height="371" Margin="10,40,12,4">
                <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80">Import Path:</Label>
                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="81,7,0,0" Name="txtImportPath" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="txtImportPath_TextChanged" Text="C:\Users\cachambers\Desktop\Nintendo_WiiUQSDRC2011_FI_final_Rev2\Extracted" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="757"></TextBox>
                <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,138,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80">Code Set:</Label>
                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="80,141,17,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="C:\Users\cachambers\Desktop\Nintendo_ModelTest\Extracted" ></TextBox>
                <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,204,0,0" Name="btnImport" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnImport_Click">Import</Button>
                <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,170,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68">Bits/Token:</Label>
                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="79,172,0,0" Name="txtBitsPerToken" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="51">4</TextBox>
                <Label Content="Export Path:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,35,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="80,36,17,0" Name="txtExportPath" Text="C:\Users\cachambers\Desktop\Nintendo_WiiUQSDRC2011_FI_final_Rev2\Compressed" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Config Path:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,65,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="79,66,18,0" Name="txtConfigPath" Text="C:\Users\cachambers\Desktop\Nintendo_WiiUQSDRC2011_FI_final_Rev2\Config" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Device Type:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="844,6,0,0" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="919,7,182,0" Name="txtDeviceType" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <CheckBox Content="Root path to subdirectores" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="980,10,0,0" Name="chkRecursive" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" />
                <Button Content="Package" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,204,0,0" Name="btnPackage" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnPackage_Click" />
                <Button Content="Validate" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,204,0,0" Name="btnValidate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnValidate_Click" />
                <Label Content="Frequency Tolerance:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,170,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,172,0,0" Name="txtFreqTolerance" Text="0.05" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" />
                <Label Content="Edge Tolerance:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317,170,0,0" Name="label8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,172,0,0" Name="txtEdgeTolerance" Text="0.05" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" />
                <Label Content="Library Version:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="466,170,0,0" Name="label9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="556,172,0,0" Name="txtLibVersion" Text="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" />
                <Label Content="Encoding Methodology:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="613,170,0,0" Name="label10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,172,339,0" Name="txtEncodingMethodology" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" />
                <CheckBox Content="Single Functions" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="chkSingleFunctions" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="932,175,0,0" />
                <CheckBox Content="Single Codes" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="chkSingleCodes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="832,175,0,0" />
            </Grid>


                    </TabItem>

 <!-- relevant section Visual tab START -->
                <TabItem Header="Visual" Name="tabItemZCLFileVisualizer" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Height="auto" Width="auto" >
                    <Grid Name="gridZCLFileVisualizer">

                            <TreeView Margin="10,24,734,0"  Name="ZCltreeView" MouseUp="ZCltreeView_MouseUp" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                           <TextBox Name ="TextBoxHexFile"  Height="Auto" Margin="483,24,24,10" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" FontFamily="Courier New"/>
                        <Label Content="ZCL hierarchy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146"/>
                        <Label Content="ZCL file's hex view" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="483,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146"/>

                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <!-- relevant section Visual tab END -->

            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Window>][1]][1]
```

**This the problem:**
[image]

Comment: Part of your problem is a poor layout. All the **funky fixed sizes & margins** are causing your immediate issue. Instead you should refactor layout using something like Grid to be responsive instead of all those fixed sizes and margins you got from just using the WYSIWYG editor. Second issue you may run into, keep in mind a TextBox will only display roughly 32k characters.

Comment: Just to share my simple experience, all the things in my application are clipped like you at the end of the Window. So, I made the Window taller(bigger) or made the things(WPF controls) shorter(less tall). It seems little bug but I just let it happens and modify sizes correspondingly. Hope this help..

Comment: @KayLee That's basically advocating poor layout practices. Not recommended.

Comment: @ChrisW. However, Microsoft might be going to pursuit an ultimate way something like WYSIWYG.

Comment: WYSIWYG will likely never be the "ultimate way" unfortunately. It's meant for beginners or quickie projects. However like anything else, if you want to use something to it's full capacity you'll need to learn how it works. :)